# asp.net logout using php curl

Tags: php, asp.net, curl, logout

I want to logout the asp.net page using PHP curl, I've that .net page logout URL.
Then i tried the below PHP code for logout.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $logoutUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
if($curl_errno){
     echo $curl_errno;
}
curl_close($ch);
```

But it's not working, when i hit the logout URL in browser, the logout is working.

What is the best way to logout the .net page URL(https://hostname/logout.aspx)
thanks in advance for you better support and idea

Comment: I assume that you have to pass user's cookie file - cause in other case .net can't understand which user is trying to logout

Comment: Login Scenario: i have two website www.abc.com and www.123.com, when i hit the abc.com login it'll redirect to the 123.com login page, after login it will redirect to the abc.com
Logout Scenario: when i hit the abc.com logout then 123.com also should need to logout automattically, for that i am using curl in abc.com and pass the 123.com logout url using curl

Comment: so, you need to somehow grab user session for 123 on abc site. the simplest way is to have a token, which can be used to find user. look for example for jwt token generation. it can be some-kind of way. or just add user id to your logout page and send a curl request: abc.com/logout?user_id=123